# Is there a simple way of inverting more than one minimatch expression?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, minimatch

I have the following two minimatch expressions being used within Grunt tasks:

```
files: ['background/**/*', 'common/**/*', 'contentScript/youTubePlayer/**/*', 'foreground/**/*', 'test/**/*', '!**/main.js']

files: ['**/*', '!**/background/**', '!**/common/**', '!contentScript/youTubePlayer/**/*', '!**/foreground/**', '!**/test/**',  '**/main.js', '!**/less/**']
```

The second expression inversely mirrors the first expression such that all files which are included in the first expression are excluded in the second and, similarly, all files which are excluded from the first are included in the second.

I'd like to keep these two expressions in-sync. I know how to do this with plain JS... such as:

```
var inverseFiles = files.map(function(file){
    return file.charAt(0) === '!' ? file.slice(1) : ('!' + file) 
});
```

I'm wondering if there's anything simpler with Grunt, or if this would be an appropriate way to ensure these two expressions mirror each other?

Comment: You could use https://github.com/sevenweb/gitignore-globs/ (pass in a custom file instead of gitignore)